# Can benzene diazonium chloride always participate in a coupling reaction with any compound that contains a phenyl group?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I know that benzene diazonium chloride couples with phenol and aniline. One N atom of the diazonium ion forms a bond with the carbon at the para postion of the ring. That made me think, can a coupling reaction occur between benzene diazonium chloride and say, benzene or chlorobenzene or any compound that has a phenyl group?Ann if not, then what kind of compounds will it react with?

Comment: Only strongly activated rings - primarily what you mentioned. If it could react with benzene, you'd probably see such example.